# Degree of pull-back of locally free sheaves under normalization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a projective, nodal curve, $\pi:\tilde{X} \to X$ be its normalization and $\mathcal{L}$ be an invertible sheaf on $X$. The question is: Is $\deg(\pi^*\mathcal{L})=\deg(\mathcal{L})$?

As stated in Proposition $2.1$ of [this](http://www.mat.ufmg.br/~dan/artigos/torsion-free.pdf) note, this seems to be the case. However, I am not able to follow the proof or the reference mentioned in this note.

Any hint/reference for this question will also be very welcome.

Comment: Any invertible sheaf can be written as $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ for some Cartier divisor on $X$. Further, if $X$ is a curve (singular or not), we can choose $D$ such that $D$ is not supported at any of the singular points. Then degree of the invertible sheaf is $\deg D$ and since near $D$, $\pi$ is an isomorphism, we get pull back is same as $\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(D)$ and thus degree does not change.